# Java error "Index 6 out of bounds for length 6"

Tags: java

¿Alguien me podría echar una mano? No entiendo porque sale de los límites, me ocurre tanto en el st1 como en el st2. El programa trata sobre insertar dos cadenas y ver si los carácteres del String st2 están contenidos en el String st1, da igual el orden. Para ello he guardado carácter por carácter en dos arrays y los he ido recorriendo para comprobarlo. Gracias de antemano.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EjStringCont{
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String st1 = "Hola a todos, hoy es Sabado";
        String st2 = "ahysxx";
        System.out.println(isInside(st1, st2));
    }
    public static boolean isInside(String contenedor, String seq){
        char[] arrayChar = new char[contenedor.length()];
        char[] arraySeq=new char[seq.length()];

        contenedor=contenedor.toLowerCase();
        seq=seq.toLowerCase();

        // Guardamos los strings en dos arrays, cada posicion es un char
        for(int i=0;i<contenedor.length();i++){
            arrayChar[i]=contenedor.charAt(i);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<seq.length();i++){
            arraySeq[i]=seq.charAt(i);
        }

        boolean cont=true;
        // Recorremos los dos arrays haciendo todas las combinaciones posibles
        for(int i=0;i<arrayChar.length && cont==true;i++){
            boolean encontrado=false;
            for(int j=0;i<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++){
                if(arraySeq[j]==arrayChar[i]){
                    encontrado=true;
                }
            }
            if(encontrado==false){
                cont=false;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
}
```

Comment: En el segudno for, tienes puesto  **for(int j=0;i<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++)** en lugar de  **for(int j=0;j<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++)**. Estas comparando el valor con la i, del for anterior. Tal vez esto sea tu problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenas el error que tienes es simplemente que has puesto `for(int j=0;i<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++){` en lugar de `for(int j=0;j<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++){` ve que has puesto `i<arraySeq.length` y no `j<arraySeq.length`

El bucle te quedaría de la siguiente forma

```java
for(int i=0;i<arrayChar.length && cont==true;i++){
            boolean encontrado=false;
            for(int j=0;j<arraySeq.length && encontrado==false;j++){
                if(arraySeq[j]==arrayChar[i]){
                    encontrado=true;
                }
            }
            if(encontrado==false){
                cont=false;
            }
        }
```

A mayores te dejo por aqui una simplificacion de tu codigo usando `foreach` si quieres puedes investigar sobre `lambda` y `stream` para ver como hacerlo de forma mas sencilla usando `listas` en lugar de bucles:

```java
public static boolean isInside(String contenedor, String seq) {
        char[] arrayChar = new char[contenedor.length()];
        char[] arraySeq = new char[seq.length()];

        contenedor = contenedor.toLowerCase();
        seq = seq.toLowerCase();

        // Guardamos los strings en dos arrays, cada posicion es un char
        for (int i = 0; i < contenedor.length(); i++) {
            arrayChar[i] = contenedor.charAt(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < seq.length(); i++) {
            arraySeq[i] = seq.charAt(i);
        }

        boolean cont = true;
        // Recorremos los dos arrays haciendo todas las combinaciones posibles
        for (char value : arrayChar) {
            boolean encontrado = false;
            for (char c : arraySeq) {
                if (c == value) {
                    encontrado = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!encontrado) {
                cont = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cont;
    }
```

Te dejo por aqui una forma mas recomendable y entendible de tu codigo:

```java
    public static boolean isInside(final String contenedor, final String seq) {
        return Arrays.stream(seq.split("")) // Se pasa el string a un stream
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()) // Se pasa a un set para eliminar repetidos
            .stream() // Se vuelve a pasar a strearm
            .map(String::toLowerCase) // Se pasan a minuscula todas las letras
            .allMatch(c -> contenedor.toLowerCase().contains(c)); // Si todas las letras se encuentra devuelve true
    }
```

Comment: Correcto!! Eso era!! Muchas gracias, me estaba explotando la cabeza revisándolo 200 veces. Un saludo

Comment: Si te ha servido, marca la respuesta como correcta para futuros usuarios que tengan un problema similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hola @Cerme09 he echo una prueba i me ha funcionado. tienes el bucle final mal.
Te mando el código que he probado, solamente la función de isInside.

```
 public static boolean isInside(String contenedor, String seq){
    char[] arrayChar = new char[contenedor.length()];
    char[] arraySeq = new char[seq.length()];
    
    contenedor=contenedor.toLowerCase();
    seq=seq.toLowerCase();
    
     // Guardamos los strings en dos arrays, cada posicion es un char
    for(int i=0;i<contenedor.length();i++){
        arrayChar[i]=contenedor.charAt(i);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<seq.length();i++){
        arraySeq[i]=seq.charAt(i);
    }
    
    boolean cont=true;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Recorremos los dos arrays haciendo todas las combinaciones posibles
   for(int a = 0; a < arrayChar.length; a++){
       for(var b = 0; b < arraySeq.length; b++){
           if(arrayChar[a] == arraySeq[b]){
               
               String ok = "Encontrado: ";
               String str1 = Character.toString(arraySeq[b]);
               String result = ok.concat(str1);
               System.out.println(result);
           }
       }
   }
    return cont;
}
```

Lo que hago es recorro el primer bucle, a la vez recorro el segundo si encuentra el mismo carácter te lo detecta y te lo imprime.